# How do I get elements of a hash whose keys match a given regex?

Tags: perl

How do I get elements of a hash whose keys match a given regex? without usign any module (e.g Tie::RegexpHash)

How to achieve this ?

```
%s = (
        'as2-queen' => 1 ,
        'as1-queen' => 2,
    );


my $regex = qr/queen/ ;

if ( $s{$regex}) {
  print " I am here " ;
}
```

~

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your question is not very clear as your problem is probably not just about "using" a regex as a hash key, but it's about getting some output you've not explained.

I suppose that your question could be rephrased as *"How do I get elements of a hash whose keys match a given regex?"* If this is the case, the following code will work for you:

```
my $regex = qr/queen/;
print "$_ => $s{$_}\n" for grep $regex, keys %s;
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing you're trying to match keys in the hash using a regex.

If so, use grep on the list of keys:

```
%s = (
        'as2-queen' => 1 ,
        'as1-queen' => 2,
    );

my ($first_matching_key) = grep { $_ =~ /queen/ } keys %s;

print "First matching key is $first_matching key\n";
print "Corresponding value is $s{$first_matching_key}\n";
```

Is that what you meant?

Comment: Did you try your solution ? `$first_matching_key` contains the number of keys that match `/queen/`

Answer (score 1):

Use [smart matching](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Smart-matching-in-detail) in Perl 5.10.1 and above:

```
use 5.010;
use strict;
use warnings;

my %s = (
        'as2-queen' => 1 ,
        'as1-queen' => 2,
    );


my $regex = qr/queen/ ;

if ($regex ~~ %s) {
    say "I am here" ;
}

# Or perhaps cleaner
if (%s ~~ $regex) {
    say "I am here" ;
}

# More or less equivalent, in pre-5.10 code
if (grep { /$regex/ } keys %s) {
    say "I am here" ;
}
```

Comment: Or just `if (%s ~~ /queen/) { say "Here I am" }` since `%hash ~~ $rx` is defined as a shortcircuiting `grep` of the keys for the pattern.