# How do I find out if a string begins with key of a hash table?

Tags: perl

I need to check a specific substring of each line of a big file if the substring begins with one of a set of strings. Since I also need another attribute for each possible key, I've currently represented the search strings and associated values in a hash:

```
my %nops = (   # Name and length of needed headers
                 'POS1'     => 308,
                 'POS2'     => 305,
                 'POSSBNOP' => 309,
                 'PERFORAT' => 10,
                 'DOCVV'    => 305,
                 'SPOOLING' => 308,
                 'DOCADR'   => 305,
                 'DOCFARBE' => 305,
                 'DOCMAIL'  => 305,
               );
```

The maximal length of the search string is 8 characters, so I'm extracting the substring from each line of the input file. Some examples of possible substrings are my test data:

```
my @nop = ( 'POS1 000', # matches 'POS1'
            'ABCDEF00', # no match (this would be the vast majority of lines in a file)
            'SPOOLING', # matches 'SPOOLING'
            'POS2 Rec', # matches 'POS2'
          );
```

I have a working solution, which requires me to iterate over the keys of the hash to find the right entry if it exists:

```
for my $n (@nop) { # 
    while ( my ($key, $value) = each(%nops) ) {
        if ( $n =~ /^$key/ ) {
            print "NOP $key found, length $value\n";
            last;
        }
    }
}
```

I am not happy with the solution, because it means running through all the iterations of the while loop for the majority of lines in the file.

I found another partial solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26152923/test-if-a-string-contains-the-key-of-a-hash-in-perl), which I like for its conciseness, but it tells me only which lines match, not the key which matched, which I need to figure out the hash value:

```
my $nop_keys = qr/${\ join('|', map quotemeta, keys %nops) }/;
for my $n (@nop) { # 
    print "String matched: $n\n" if $n =~ $nop_keys;
}
```

Are there better ways to solve this problem? [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4874946/how-do-i-get-elements-of-a-hash-whose-keys-match-a-given-regex) looks relevant, but deals with the opposite situation: the string matches the key, not the other way round. Maybe a different data structure would be more efficient here?

Side conditions: I'm on Perl 5.10.0, and can only install any additional packages that already come with SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 SP2 (no CPAN available).

Comment: If you capture the alternation it will return what was matched.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to capture what matched.

```
my $pat = join '|', map quotemeta, keys %nops;
my $re = qr/$pat/;

for my $n (@nop) {
   my ($key) = $n =~ /^($re)/
      or next;

   my $val = $nops{$key};

   ...
}
```

Comment: That was the missing bit of information, got it to work this way. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can more efficiently deal with this by capturing **up to 8 non-space characters** from the start of each line, and using simple hash lookups.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my %nops = (
    # Name and length of needed headers
    'POS1'     => 308,
    'POS2'     => 305,
    'POSSBNOP' => 309,
    'PERFORAT' => 10,
    'DOCVV'    => 305,
    'SPOOLING' => 308,
    'DOCADR'   => 305,
    'DOCFARBE' => 305,
    'DOCMAIL'  => 305,
);

while (my $line = <DATA>) {
    my ($key) = ($line =~ /\A ( \S{1,8} ) /x);
    next unless $key and exists( $nops{ $key } );
    print "$key => $nops{ $key }\n";
}

__DATA__
POS1 000 # matches 'POS1'
ABCDEF00 # no match (this would be the vast majority of lines in a file)
SPOOLING # matches 'SPOOLING'
POS2 Rec # matches 'POS2'
```

Output:

```
POS1 => 308
SPOOLING => 308
POS2 => 305
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not always the case that the header name is followed by a space, so this solution won't work in my specific case, but might be useful when you can be sure that the header name is delimited in some way.

Answer (score 0):

Split the query and use it as a look up in the hash:

```
foreach(@nop){
    my ($id) = split;
    print "$id\n" if $nops{$id};
}
```

This assumes the key is separated from the rest of the string by whitespace.